# convert flv to mp3 with Java

Tags: java, video, cross-platform, mp3, flv

I'm pretty new in developing programs in Java. I'm currently writing a program that converts a flv video into mp3. 
I have already written such a program in Visual Studio.net C#, but the Problem is, that it isn't cross platform compatible...
I used the ffmpeg binary to convert the video into mp3, but I can't find ffmpeg binaries for Mac and Linux. (if so, I could start the specific binaries from java, depending on the OS)
So I tried to convert the video with Xuggle, but the final mp3 has 0 bytes. My current code is the following:

```
IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader("video.flv");
reader.addListener(ToolFactory.makeWriter("music.mp3", reader));
while (reader.readPacket() == null)
         do {} while(false);
```

Thanks in advance.

p.s sorry for my bad english

Comment: ffmpeg can be built for Mac OSX and is usually installed on Linux - you can probably ship binaries for MacOSX machines, but may want to require the user install ffmpeg on Linux since configurations vary

Comment: isn't there a command-line-program out for mac, that is like the ffmpeg binary for windows? (so that I can start it with parameters). I don't have a Mac, so I don't know how to build ffmpeg for mac.

Comment: If you don't have a Mac to test on, then you shouldn't bother trying to publish a Mac version for now. Java might be cross-platform, but there are usually various small problems that need to be fixed when you port. And if you're introducing native code into the mix, then it greatly increases the number of things that could go wrong.

Comment: It's harder to get a Windows binary of `ffmpeg` than a Linux one, so don't let that stop you :-P